# cannot login to my aws spot instance even though it is running

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I cannot login to my aws spot instance even though it is running. I am not able to access my data through ssh or scp. I know that my pem key works for other instances, so its not an issue with the pem key.

ssh -i my_pem_key.pem ubuntu@my_dns_name
  and I get
  Permission denied (publickey).

What can I do to retrieve my data that's in the running spot instance ? 
I tried creating an image (AMI) of the instance and logging into the new instance, but that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple things going on here.  Have you tried the following?

- Make sure the security settings on your instance are set up to use the same PEM credentials
- Verify the DNS or IP address of the server you are trying to connect to is correct

From the Amazon Docs:

> Verify that you are connecting with the appropriate user name for your AMI. Enter the user name in the Host name box in the PuTTY Configuration window.
>
> - For an Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is ec2-user.
> - For a RHEL5 AMI, the user name is either root or ec2-user.
> - For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is ubuntu.
> - For a Fedora AMI, the user name is either fedora or ec2-user.
> - For SUSE Linux, the user name is root.
>
>   Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don't work, check with the AMI provider.

Also,

> Verify that you have an inbound security group rule to allow inbound traffic to the appropriate port.

Regards

Comment: My DNS is correct..Username is ubuntu, so that is right as well. And the inbound security group is all set properly. What do you mean by check with AMI provider ?

Comment: did this get resolved - I am having the same issue
I created a spot instance which is persisted - everything was fine till I shutdown the instance, now when I boot up I cannot ssh

This is not a security group or instance key issue
I have another on-demand instance which is in the same security group and instance key and it works well